# Spring Stream oAuth 2.0 Authentication

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, tcp, spring-cloud-stream

I have a Spring Stream application with a 'Source -> Transformer -> Sink' flow in which I send TCP/IP messages, they are not HTTP messages.

I would like to use Spring Security OAuth 2.0 to secure this application using scopes. I have already implemented this in a REST Controller Client-Server application, but I don't know how to adapt it.

The idea would be to configure security using application.properties and use a tag like @EnableOAuth2Client or @EnableOAuth2SSO (Do not know which one, because I have to use client-credentials grant type).

And I would like to check the token using an annotation like @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope()").

Is this possible? Where could I check an example?

The key point is that I am using TCP/IP messages and that I have no access to a login web page, therefore no Authentication Grant Type. (Everything has to be done automatically).